# Same function different elements

Tags: jquery

I would like to have the `#conceptTwo` div act the same way as the `#conceptOne` div, while using their respective buttons but the same function. Can someone suggest the best way to incorporate variables to achieve this?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".btn1").click(function() {
    $("#conceptOne").slideUp();
  });
  $(".btn2").click(function() {
    $("#conceptOne").slideDown();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>This is concept one</p>
<div id="conceptOne" style="border-style: solid; border-width: 5px;">
  Concept Content
</div>
<button class="btn1">Slide up</button>
<button class="btn2">Slide down</button>

<p>This is concept two</p>
<div id="conceptTwo" style="border-style: solid; border-width: 5px;">
  Concept Content
</div>
<button class="btn3">Slide up</button>
<button class="btn4">Slide down</button>
```

Comment: Very strange: you ask for help, get 6 answers back and do not give marks to anyone. I should not think you need any help in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would make it relative to the divs so that you don't have to specify every button and div

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".su").click(function() {
    $(this).prev().slideUp();
  });
  $(".sd").click(function() {
    $(this).prev().prev().slideDown();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>This is concept one</p>
<div id="conceptOne" style="border-style: solid; border-width: 5px;">
  Concept Content
</div>
<button class="su">Slide up</button>
<button class="sd">Slide down</button>

<p>This is concept two</p>
<div id="conceptTwo" style="border-style: solid; border-width: 5px;">
  Concept Content
</div>
<button class="su">Slide up</button>
<button class="sd">Slide down</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the prev function 
https://api.jquery.com/prev/

I haven't tested it, but should work something similar to this:

```
$(".btn1").click(function(){
    $(this).prev("div").slideUp();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    
    $(".btn1").on("click",function(){
        $(this).prevAll("#conceptOne,#conceptTwo").eq(0).slideUp(500);
        
    })
    
    $(".btn2").on("click",function(){
        $(this).prevAll("#conceptOne,#conceptTwo").eq(0).slideDown(500);
    })
    
    
})
```

```html
<p>This is concept one</p>
        <div id="conceptOne" style="border-style: solid; border-width: 5px;">
            Concept Content
        </div>
        <button class="btn1">Slide up</button>
        <button class="btn2">Slide down</button>

        <p>This is concept two</p>
        <div id="conceptTwo" style="border-style: solid; border-width: 5px;">
            Concept Content
        </div>
        <button class="btn1">Slide up</button>
        <button class="btn2">Slide down</button>
        
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

IMO, you should use only one button using `slideToggle()`

As you said that you want respective button to click but the same function, I would recommend to use a single button and provide respective selector to the DIV.

Official documentation of [slideToggle()](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/)

See example for more details.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".slide1").click(function() {
    $('#'+$(this).attr('class')).slideToggle();
  });
  $(".slide2").click(function() {
    $('#'+$(this).attr('class')).slideToggle();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>This is concept one</p>
<div id="slide1" style="border-style: solid; border-width: 5px;">
  Concept Content
</div>
<button class="slide1">Slide Toggle</button>

<p>This is concept two</p>
<div id="slide2" style="border-style: solid; border-width: 5px;">
  Concept Content
</div>
<button class="slide2">Slide Toggle</button>
```

Comment: Using one single 'toggle' button is efficient, although not necessarily clear for all users. Nevertheless if you opt for it, then the wording of the title of the button should be set according to the status of the button: titles such as 'toggle' might be misleading, especially inside a more complex UI.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try just writing a function?

```
$(document).ready(function() {

function slideIt(x){

x.slideToggle();

}


  $(".btn1, .btn2").click(function() {

var conceptOne = $("#conceptOne");

slideIt(conceptOne);
});

  $(".btn3, .btn4").click(function() {

var conceptTwo = $("#conceptTwo");

slideIt(conceptTwo);
});
```

Comment: This certainly works, Steven, but you are not taking advantage of the power of the jQuery wrapper. See my own answer.

Answer (score 0):

There might be many different solutions. Mine is fairly simple and essentially relies on including each 'concept' and 'up' and 'down' buttons in separate `<div>'s` :

```
<!-- …  -->
    <div id="zone1">    
        <div  id="concept1" style="border-style: solid; border-width: 5px;">
          Concept Content
        </div>
        <button class="btn1">Slide up</button>
        <button class="btn2">Slide down</button>       
    </div>

    <div id="zone2"> 
        <p>This is concept two</p>
        <div id="concept2" style="border-style: solid; border-width: 5px;">
          Concept Content
        </div>
        <button class="btn1">Slide up</button>
        <button class="btn2">Slide down</button>
    </div>

    <script>
      $(".btn1").click(function() { $("div", this.parentNode).slideUp(); });
      $(".btn2").click(function() { $("div", this.parentNode).slideDown(); });
    </script>     
</body>
</html>
```

Advantages

a) as to the structure of the DOM, you need only add one `<div>` per 'concept', but, what is more, this will enable you to easily format each 'concept' with rich features;

b) the method (slideUp/Down) will be applied efficiently for the DOM-adressing jQuery wrapper is very specific. `this.parentNode` is called the 'context' of the selector.

c) your JS code should be appended right before de `</body>` tag of your page. You do not need to call `$(document).ready`…

d) be that as it may, according to good coding practices, you should deport your JS code from you html page.

e) as to the styling, same as d).